# Library project dependency built as APK

Tags: android, eclipse, build, compilation

I'm using an external library in my project.

I downloaded the code from github and added the project to my eclipse workspace. After I went to my MainApp, I added the Project Folder as library.

Everytime I compile the MainApp, the dependency will also be build as APK. When I'm using the external library in another project, it's the same behavior. Why it happens?

> [2013-02-09 20:57:50 - MainApp] Installing MainApp.apk...
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:25 - MainApp] Success!
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:25 - MainApp] Project dependency found, installing: AndroidBillingLibrary
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:25 - AndroidBillingLibrary] Uploading AndroidBillingLibrary.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:26 - AndroidBillingLibrary] Installing AndroidBillingLibrary.apk...
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:29 - AndroidBillingLibrary] Success!
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:29 - MainApp] Starting activity de.MainAppapp.activities.SplashActivity on device emulator-5556
>   [2013-02-09 20:58:31 - MainApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=de.MainAppapp/.activities.SplashActivity }

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, So far I had following solution:

1. Mark the external library as Library project (as you have shown in pic)
2. Clean all projects and wait till your main application project builds up itself using external library
3. Unmark "Is Library" check on External Library
4. Now You can install your Application

At the installation it will look for APK of external library and it can find it easily, since its not library project anymore. But if it is still marked, it couldn't find apk file for that library. Anyway this is how i trick it. But I'm sure there is better solution for that, just i didn't figure it out yet !